# Codeigniter Session sent error

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am kind of new to codeigniter framework. I'm dealing with an issue which I couldn't face at production time. The error is not understandable or readable. I have the error log. I did debug research which concluded with failure. Please help me to solve the issue. I have done all proper declaration on session library initiation and it worked perfectly with testing environment with local host. I have attached the error log with this question. Please help me to solve this. Thanks all

> ERROR - 2017-08-18 00:34:53 --> Severity: Warning --> Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/stayinka/fs.stayinkandy.com/Testing/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)
>   /home/stayinka/fs.stayinkandy.com/Testing/system/core/Common.php 564

Comment: You are getting this when access certain route. Please, share related controller code.

Comment: Anytime you have code that attempts to send/modify cookie contents (which session can do), and it tries to do that after ANYTHING has been output to the browser, you will get an error like that. Post some code so we can figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: if you have any white spaces in your controller or modals first line., remove it., or check there anything did you print or echo in controller function,

Comment: <?php
class Mis_home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{ 
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('Mishome_model');
}

public function index()
{ 
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn_user'])||empty($_SESSION['loggedIn_user'])||$_SESSION['loggedIn_user']==null||$_SESSION['loggedIn_user']==false)
{
redirect('/LIn');
}
else
{
$this->load->view('MISHomeView');
}
}

Comment: This is the model function which called during login
<code>
if($data1!=null)
    {
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo'); 
     $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()); 

     $data1['LoggedInTime'] = $date;
     $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn_user', $data1);
    
     return 2;
    }
    else
    {
     return 0;
    } </code>